# Django comments flag "cancel" returns wrong url

Tags: django

I've set up django's built in comments in my application and I'm employing the flagging ability. The flagging works fine, but the 'cancel" link that appears on the template returns the following error:

```
could not find http
```

The template/form is as follows:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block title %}{% trans "Flag this comment" %}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h3>{% trans "Are you sure you want to flag this comment?" %}</h3>
<br />
 <blockquote>{{ comment|linebreaks }}</blockquote>
 <form action="." method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{% if next %}<div><input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" id="next" /></div>{% endif %}
<p class="submit">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger button-left" name="submit" value="{% trans "Flag" %}" /> or <a href="{{ comment.get_absolute_url }}">cancel</a>
</p>
  </form>
 {% endblock %}
```

Any insight into this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it might be that you're site settings aren't correct.  Check the sites app and see if you can make some changes there to get it working.